# output the right word

Tags: c, string, words

i need to output a word, which i enter a number of it.. I can't how i should assign a number to a word. Here is i use a func `strtok()` for breaking my sentence on words, then im lost..
 for exmp: " hhh jjjj kkkkk llllll" i entered `3` it ouputs :`kkkkk`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80],*p;
    char sp[20]=" ";
    int i,n=0,num;
    printf("Enter your line: ");
    gets(str);
    p=strtok(str,sp);
    while (p!=NULL){
        for(i=0;i<p;i++){
            printf("%s - [%d]\n",p,i+1);
            p=strtok(NULL,sp);
            n=p;
        }
        n++;
    }
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num==n){
        printf("%s",p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()` ever. It is too dangerous.

Comment: Show your Input and Output expected.

Comment: Create an array of words, i.e. an array of char[], each item will contain a word. And pay attention to the index, arrays are 0-based, in human mind there are more likely 1-based.

Comment: The double loop is dubious at best; I'd rate it as wrong.  You don't seem to have an array pointing to the words, which makes it hard to access a word by number.  Remember that `strtok()` destroys its input by scribbling null bytes on the input string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY for exmp: " hhh jjjj kkkkk llllll"
i entered `3`
it ouputs : `kkkkk`

Comment: @NikitaGusev - Please edit your question to include this information

Comment: If you enter the number before you start tokenizing the line, you do not have to keep the words in an array - just call `strtok` *n* times, then output the string it returns. That would make the program short, 10..15 lines or so.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/5cDg67)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you,should i post it like an answer?

Comment: Please post  an answer with an explanation.

Comment: Please compile with high warning level and you will get a warning about "i<p".

Answer (score 0):

1) should not use `gets`. That's why here is `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);`

2) i enter a number of a word **BEFORE** i start tokenizing the line

3) the main algorithm is in this :

`while (p != NULL && n < num){
        if(++n == num){
        printf("%s\n", p);
        break;
        }
    p=strtok(NULL, sp);
       }`

in my loop n rises while it finds word,when a user enters a number and IF it equally to num,so it breaks out of a loop and print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(void){
        char str[80], *p;
        const char *sp = " \n";
        int n = 0, num = 0;

        printf("Enter your line: ");
        fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
        printf("n: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        p = strtok(str, sp);
        while (p != NULL && n < num){
            if(++n == num){
                printf("%s\n", p);
                break;
            }
            p=strtok(NULL, sp);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```